# jQuery append seems to ghost append in an _.each statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

As strange as it sounds my code is simply this :

```
$element = "<div>Testing</div>";
_.each($('.chat-messages'), function(el) {
  el.append($element);
  debugger;
});
```

If I inspect from the `debugger`, when I type `el` in console, I can clearly see that `$element.el` was successfully appended. However, when I go and click continue, the element was never added.

The `$('.chat-messages')` selector returns two objects. The second was has `$element.el` added just fine to it. The first one doesn't. Even though the first one definitely returns the same kind of object as the second one. And in the debugger, I can clearly see that the object was appended to `el`. It just is never added to the actual HTML. Just the representational object within the debugger.

Am I just not selecting `el` correctly? How could the first and second one be different?

Comment: what is `_` here? underscore/loadash or something? and why is that here?

Comment: what happens when you remove or comment `debugger` line,, it is also not appended?

Comment: If you're using jQuery you should use `$(.chat-messages').each()`, not `_.each()`.

Comment: Are you really setting `$element` to a string, or is it something like `$element = $("<div>Testing</div>");`?

Comment: If you put `$()` around it, there's just one element, and each time you append it, the element is moved, not copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This works fine although I had to use `timeout` because the div wasn't rendering until then
- Do you think you have a similar problem like the UI isn't rendered yet?
- This code works if the $element as the OP originally asked is a string value `"<div>Testing</div>"`

```js
var f = function() {
  $element = "<div>Testing</div>";
  _.each($('.chat-messages'), function(el) {
    el.append($element);
    //debugger;
  });
};

setTimeout(f, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='chat-messages'>
<div class='chat-messages'>
<div class='chat-messages'>
<div class='chat-messages'>
```

EDIT:

- After going through the comments, I did a quick research of how the [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) works and what happens if we swap the `$element` with an actual `$("<div>Testing</div>")` only to find out that the comments were true

Note 1:
 - The `$.each` is not required as you can choose all the elements matching the result and append at once

```js
var f = function() {
  $element = $("<div>Testing</div>");
  $('.chat-messages').append($element);
};

setTimeout(f, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='chat-messages'></div>
<div class='chat-messages'></div>
<div class='chat-messages'></div>
<div class='chat-messages'></div>
```

Now lets use `$.each`

```js
var f = function() {
  $element = $("<div>Testing</div>");
  $('.chat-messages').each(function(ix, el) {
    $(el).append($element);
  });
};
setTimeout(f, 100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='chat-messages'></div>
<div class='chat-messages'></div>
<div class='chat-messages'></div>
<div class='chat-messages'></div>
```

Note 2:

- Use of each to iterate through the elements and appending will not yield the desired result as explained in the comments and also append documentation (pasting it below)

> You can also select an element on the page and insert it into
>   another:
>
> $( ".container" ).append( $( "h2" ) );
>
> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location
>   elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned):

Comment: $.each did the trick. For some reason _.each was making some kind of illusive imaginary object and appending it. But then after the _.each function ran it's course, everything returned to normal. However $.each actually made a static change.